# Adding a jQuery Plugin into a Ruby on Rails App

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working on a website that uses HTML, CSS, and JavaScript with jQuery plugins. In order to make the website more dynamic, I shifted my code to Ruby on Rails. The HTML and CSS are fine, but some of the jQuery plugins that I had working before aren't functioning anymore.

I tried multiple ways to fix this. I first added the javascript files into `app/assets/javascripts` and then added `//= require pluginfilename` in application.js and then `<%= javascript_include_tag name..... %>` but that didn't work.

Is there something that I'm missing or doing wrong? I'm fairly new to Rails. This is version 4.2.3 btw.

Edit: this is my application.js file

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which         will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or any plugin's vendor/assets/javascripts directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/rails/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap.min
//= require turbolinks
//= require countdown
//= require grid
//= require custom
//= require script
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: have you placed the js files in the `vendor/assets/javascritps` directory? You'd then call a file named `bootstrap.min.js` like this in the `application.js` file: `//= require bootstrap.min`

Answer (score 1):

First thing I would do would be to try and find a version of the plugin that's distributed via CDN, then including it via <%= javascript_include_tag link %>.

Barring that...

Did you do a //= require pluginfilename without the extension? Can you paste in your application.js file so we can take a look?

Also, what errors are you getting your JS console? Are you ensuring that the plugin is being loaded before it's being used? (Load order in the application.js file matters.)

Answer (score 1):

You can find a bridge between Bower and Rails with [Rails-Assets.org](https://rails-assets.org). I've used this for several projects and it works nicely. If your plugins are using bower, they should exist on Rails-Assets.org